# How to I get ASP.NET Page Name

Tags: c#, asp.net

Easy one here.

I have a control inside a control inside a masterpage. The page name looks something like this in HTML

```
ctl00$MasterPageBody$MainControl$ChildControl
```

Any idea how I can get the above from code behind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the clientID property of the control.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a top-level control on the page, or at least one that isn't in any sort of repeating type, you can just use the `ClientID` property.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="testLabel" />

<script>
    $('#<%= testLabel.ClientID %>').click(function() { ... });
</script>
```

If we're talking about something that *isn't* accessible directly like that, you'll have to do the same thing, but it'll have to be wrapped in a `FindControl`. The example of that isn't so clean, so I'll trust you can understand from my words. But basically, if you have a label that shows code-behind-given text on each row of a `GridView`, you'll have to call `((Label)e.Row.FindControl("testLabel")).ClientID`. Still pretty straight-forward, but a bit more complicated than the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function similar to this:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctl, string id) {
    if (!ctl.HasControls())
        return null;
    Control res = null;
    foreach(Control c in ctl.Controls) {
        if (c.ID == id) {
            res = c;
            break;
        } else {
            res = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (res != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

in this way:

```
Control ChildControl = FindControlRecursive(this.Page, "ChildControl");
string ID = ChildControl.ClientID;
```